# Passing arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, methods, pass-by-reference

I know i can't pass arrays the way I'm doing it. Would I need to pass by reference if so how? The question is at the bottom for reference.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MethodsArrays {

    public static int[] fillArray() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = scan.nextInt();
        int array[] = new int[size];
        int pos=0;

        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
            pos=i+1;
            System.out.println("Enter element " + pos);
            array[i]=scan.nextInt();
        }
        return array;
    }

    public static int sumArray(int [] array) {
        int sum=0;

        for(int i=0; i<array.length-1; i++) {
            sum=array[i]+array[i+1];
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static int avgArray(int [] array) {
        int avg=0;
        int sum = sumArray(array);
        avg = sumArray(array)/array.length-1;
        return avg;
    }

    public static void printArray(int [] array) {
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fillArray();
        System.out.println("Sum=" + sumArray(array));
        System.out.println("Average=" + avgArray(array));
        printArray(array);
    }
}
```

> Write a Java program, called MethodsArrays that has 4 static methods
>   called fillArray(), sumArray(), avgArray(), and printArray(). The
>   fillArray() method should be called from the main method. The
>   fillArray() method should use a Scanner to take in a number
>   representing the length of the array and then read in numbers to fill
>   the array. The sumArray() method should take an int array as its input
>   parameter and returns an integer value that is the sum of all the
>   elements in the array. The avgArray() method should take an int array
>   as its input parameter and returns an integer value that is the
>   average of all the elements in the array. The printArray() method
>   should take an int array as its input parameter and has no return
>   value. It should then print out the elements of the array on the same
>   line separated by a space (“ “). All methods should work for integer
>   arrays.

Comment: You would have less problems if you would actually care about what `fillArray()` returns ...

Comment: Why can't you pass arrays the way you are doing? You just need to store the result of the call to `fillArray()` in a variable named `array` so the variable name actually exists and you can use it in the following calls.

Comment: i think that you need to assign the fillArray() result to a variable, like int[] array= fillArray();

Comment: `sum=array[i]+array[i+1];` What is this supposed to do?

Comment: Yes thanks forgot to assign the fillArray() to an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks OK. You just need to assign the result of ***fillArray()*** to a variable, in order to use this result for further methods.

It would look like:

```
 int[] array = fillArray();
 System.out.println("Sum=" + sumArray(array));
 System.out.println("Average=" + avgArray(array));
 printArray(array);
```

Comment: In `avgArray` method OP is dividing by `array.length-1`. Not sure if its intended.